# Do I need a decoupling cap for a line buffer gate?

Tags: digital-logic, decoupling-capacitor, gate-driving

The [data sheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/sn74lv1t125-286295.pdf) does not say anything about the decoupling capacitors for this buffer gate. Would it be correct to assume that no caps needed? Please, explain.

Comment: Yes. Any digital switching IC needs a cap.

Comment: Especially a line buffer, because its main job is rapidly switching high current.

Comment: All digital circuitry requires decoupling caps. There is a general guideline to use 1 cap for each VCC or VDD pin. I use 0.1uF ceramic caps with X5R dielectric. This is only a guideline. If the datasheet says different, follow the datasheet. If you consult with an expert who says to use some other rule, just use the expert's rule.

Comment: That's not something that's included on a datasheet -- take a look at datasheets for any other 74 or CD or any other series digital ICs.  Its just expected as part of best practices.

Comment: Yep. This makes sense. Just wanted to confirm. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory the chip does not need a decoupling capacitor, what it needs is a power that is within its specifications. To achieve that you can use any means you want, including magic. But the most common way to do that is to have a decoupling capacitor (or mybe more than 1) nearby, and not too much inductance in the feed line and ground.

So you can say that the power specification in the datasheet indirectly asks for a decoupling capacitor.